# pgadmin 4 версия 2.0 Проблема при вставке данных в столбцы

Tags: sql, postgresql

При одновременной вставке данных через INSERT сразу в 12 столбцов, выдает:

> Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been
>   closed.

При этом, данные в data output пустые.

[image: Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.]

Comment: Какая версия pgadmin?

Comment: Pgadmin 4, версия 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась тем, что у меня был в паре колонок неправильный формат данных.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, проблему полностью еще не исправили. Ее обсуждение есть в английской версии SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266659/pgadmin-not-connected-to-the-server-or-the-connection-to-the-server-has-been-cl

Попробуйте переустановить pdadmin, используя совет ниже:
I try reinstall (After uninstall delete all leftover data) and delete C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin (delete all data inside pgAdmin Folder) And its works

Update-> Your table name and field name must lowercase

Или же используйте pgAdmin3, в ней данной проблемы нет.